# Best tool to create "Architecture Diagrams" (not UML)

Tags: diagram

I want to create an "architecture diagram" to explain our Software (libraries, Eclipse RCP, modules, features, etc.).

1. What is the correct name for such diagrams?
2. What is a good tool to create them? (I tried Visio and Enterprise Architect but didn't find a feature for that)

Comment: looking at this after 3 years of posting and someone just edited it

Comment: https://www.draw.io/ is a very resourceful tool to have it in your list.
Standout features of Collaboration using Google Drive,Dropbox. Wide set of assets easy drag and drop, on top of it's online.

Comment: Microsoft makes available templates for Visio (etc) for mapping Azure and Enterprise architectures (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41937)

Comment: https://www.draw.io/

Comment: https://icepanel.io

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use whatever program you want as long as it can draw colored shapes.

Some people I know use PowerPoint, since you can make nice designs with it.

Or in Visio: New->General->Block Diagram. You can alter the design by right click->format->line. (You can make it more beautiful but I didn't want to spend to much time)

[image]

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Thank you. Dont forget to click on "Blocks Raised" on the left to find these.

Comment: You're not exactly good at Tetris.

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if these diagrams have a specific name, I know them as layer diagrams since the describe the layers or stacks in the architecture.

You could create those diagrams in Visio - although I don't think there is a stencil that supports it directly. You could also try a number of other tools:

- http://www.lovelycharts.com/
- http://www.gliffy.com/
- Microsoft Word (has good diagram support in later versions)
- Paint.Net / GIMP

Comment: thanks, "layer diagram" is a good name to google

Comment: Hey, if you're gonna remove my accepted answer, at least give me an upvote!! :P

Comment: sorry, i would, but i can't. rep < 15 :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what they're called, but I've never seen one more complex than only a couple of items, so you'll probably get away with drawing them in Paint even without too much effort.